# "[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" when using python's JSON library

Tags: python, ajax, json, iis

I'm using IIs 8 to run a python script to return some data.

The code should receive an AJAX call with JSON in it and return data accordingly. However, when trying to parse the JSON, I get the exception:

```
[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Here's my code:

```
import sys, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import urllib2
result = {'success': 'true'}
try:
  myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
except ValueError:
  myjson = ""
```

This is the relevant stack trace:

```
      9 result = {'success': 'true'}
     10 try:
=>   11   myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
     12 except ValueError:
     13   myjson = ""
myjson undefined, json = <module 'json' from 'C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.pyc'>, json.load = <function load>, sys = <module 'sys' (built-in)>, sys.stdin = <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r'>
 C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp=<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r'>, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw={})
    284 
    285     """
=>  286     return loads(fp.read(),
=>  287         encoding=encoding, cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
=>  288         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
global loads = <function loads>, fp = <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r'>, fp.read = <built-in method read of file object>, encoding = None, cls = None, object_hook = None, parse_float = None, parse_int = None, parse_constant = None, object_pairs_hook = None, kw = {}
```

I could not find one real reason for the exception. I gave friend of mine this code and it works on his machine, he's running Apache2, so I suspect the IIS 8 configuration to be the problem - has anyone tried that?

Comment: This seems like more of a configuration problem than a programming problem. How have you and your friend respectively set up your script to be run? Is it a traditional CGI, a WSGI, a `mod_python` script, or something else entirely? Presumably whatever you're doing is not giving the request body as `stdin`, but whatever he's doing is.